# Redundant character is being added to one of the buffers when using readv() linux system call

Tags: c, gcc, file-io, operating-system, linux-kernel

I'd encountered bug (probably) that I can't explain and I would be happy if someone can.

****I wrote the following program:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

   char arr1[5], arr2[5], arr3[5];
   struct iovec iov[3];
   ssize_t n;
   int fd, i;


    fd = open("/home/oz/Desktop/test", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror("open error");
        return (1);
    }

    iov[0].iov_base = arr1;
    iov[1].iov_base = arr2;
    iov[2].iov_base = arr3;
    iov[0].iov_len = 5;
    iov[1].iov_len = 5;
    iov[2].iov_len = 5;

    n = readv(fd, iov, 3);
    if (n == -1)
    {
        perror("read error");
        return (1);
    }


    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("Buffer %d  Content : [%s]\n", i, (char *)iov[i].iov_base);
    }


    // DEBUG - START
    printf("Total bytes read : %d\n", (int)n);
    char * TEST = iov[0].iov_base;
    printf("TEST LAST CHARACTER (int)= %d.\nTEST LENGTH = %d\n", TEST[5], (int)strlen(TEST));
    // DEBUG - END

    return 0;
```

}

**The content of the file I read from (it's a one line text file):**
123456789012345678901234567890

****The output**

```
Buffer 0  Content : [12345]
Buffer 1  Content : [67890]
Buffer 2  Content : [12345]
Total bytes read : 15
TEST LAST CHARACTER (int)= 127.
TEST LENGTH = 6
```

****My Question:**
Character with ASCII value of 127 was added to the first buffer from some unknown reason. (In my standard output I acctually see it as white square between '5' and ']' in the first line of the output.
Why does that strange thing occurred ?

Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No extra character is being added. You have two bugs in your program.

1. You reference `TEST[5]` (that is, `arr1[5]`) which is beyond the end of the `arr1` array. C ararys are zero based, so the only valid values are: `arr1[0]`, `arr1[1]`, `arr1[2]`, `arr1[3]`, and `arr1[4]`. `arr1[5]` is the *sixth* entry in the array, not the *fifth*.
2. You print a character array that doesn't have a nul termination. C strings require a terminating zero, which you do not provide. As a consequence, the run-time system happily prints whatever characters are beyond the end of the array.

Make these changes to your program:

```
printf("Buffer %d  Content : [%5.5s]\n", i, (char *)iov[i].iov_base);
...
printf("TEST LAST CHARACTER (int)= %d.\nTEST LENGTH = %d\n", TEST[4], 5);
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you're looking at TEST[5] which is the sixth character in a buffer of 5, in other words, it's totally random at this point.

Secondly, `strlen(TEST)` depends on TEST being terminated with a zero, something that `readv()`does not guarantee. The length of 6 is once again random since it depends on memory outside your buffers.